# C++ Storing variant types in map

Tags: c++, c++17

In, C++, I'd like to create a list of function pairs that define a data pipeline.
For example, given something like this:

```
FieldName: "F1"
ParserFunction: X ParseX(string s)
DestinationFn:  void Consume(X& f1)

FieldName: "F2"
ParserFunction: Y ParseY(string s)
DestinationFn:  void Consume(Y& f2)
```

I want to be able to store this list in a data structure like a map where given a string for the FieldName & Data, the right Parser and Consumer get called.

So far the best I've come up with is something like this:

```
using ParseResult = std::variant< X, Y >;
map< string, pair< std::function<ParseResult(string)>, std::function<void(ParseResult)>>
```

This allows the Parsers to be written naturally (and existing ones to be reused):

```
int StringToInt(const string& s) { return 42; }
```

But the Consumers must use variant:

```
void ConsumeInt(ParseResult i) { foo = std::get<int>(i); }
```

This works, but can have a run-time error if the parameter does not, in fact, carry an integer.  It also means that for any given application the Variant type has to declare all the possible types.  For a long converter list that can be a large number of types.

Is there a way to declare the contents of the map so that each row is fully type safe by construction, but the rows are type-variant (or type-erased)?

In other words, I want:

```
void TypesafeIntegerSink(int i) { ... }
```

and my map initializer to read like this:

```
mymap = {
    { "F1", { StringToInt, TypesafeIntegerSink } }, 
    { "F2", { StringToX, TypesafeXSink } }, 
    ....
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a clever way to construct this so that it fails to compile if the F1 Parser doesn't return an int, or if the F1 sink doesn't take an int, etc.

Comment: How do you use the parser/consumer?  I mean, together they are just `void(string)`; what is the intermediate state *for*?  I ask this, because it is that very intermediate state operation (which you don't mention) that you need to type-erase.

Comment: So... by "type safe" I assume you mean: you want a compile time error if you get types wrong? Can you give an example code which should give you a compile time error (instead of exception)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use just a single function that parses and consumes a string and build that directly with a little lambda:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string)>> mymap = {
    { "F1", [](std::string in) { TypesafeIntegerSink(StringToInt(in)); } },
    { "F2", [](std::string in) { TypesafeXSink(StringToX(in)); } },
    /* ... */
};
```

Comment: That seems so obvious. I don't think I did a good job of asking the question I was really pondering. I will try to ask it better in the future.  I think this works for my immediate case. Thanks.

Comment: This solution would greatly benefit from using `std::string_view` instead of `std::string`.